# One view for multiple sub-domains using django-hosts

Tags: python, django, django-subdomains

I need to have multiple sub domains for my project. Each sub domain represents some company. For example: company1.myproject.io, company2.myproject.io. I used [django-hosts](http://django-hosts.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) library to set up sub domains.

hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       myproject.io
127.0.0.1       www.myproject.io
127.0.0.1       company1.myproject.io
127.0.0.1       company2.myproject.io
```

settings.py:

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'
ROOT_HOSTCONF = 'core.hosts'
DEFAULT_HOST = 'www'
DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL = "http://www.myproject.io:8000"
```

core/hosts.py:

```
from hostsconf import urls as redirect_urls
host_patterns = [
    host(r'www', settings.ROOT_URLCONF, name='www'),
    host(r'(?!www).*', redirect_urls, name='wildcard'),
]
```

hostsconf/urls.py:

```
from .views import wildcard_redirect

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<path>.*)', wildcard_redirect)
]
```

hostsconf/views.py:

```
DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL = getattr(settings, "DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL", "http://www.myproject.io:8000")

def wildcard_redirect(request, path=None):
    new_url = DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL
    if path is not None:
        new_url = DEFAULT_REDIRECT_URL + "/" + path
    return HttpResponseRedirect(new_url)
```

I have a few problems now:

1. When I go to myproject.io it succesfully redirects me to the www.myproject.io. But when I go to company1.myproject.io I got an `Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'company1.myproject.io:8000'. You may need to add u'company1.myproject.io' to ALLOWED_HOSTS`
   Do I really need each time add new host to ALLOWED_HOSTS when I got new sub domain or I am doing something wrong?
2. How to implement a single view for all sub-domains where will be dynamic context for each company. Basically I need to make queries into the db by sub domain name. Example:

   ```
   def home_page(request):
       subdomain = 'somehow get sub domain (company1 or company2)'
       comp = User.objects.get(domain_name=subdomain)
       return redirect(request, 'tpl.html', {"company": comp})
   ```

UPDATE:
Figured out how to handle ALLOWED_HOSTS and get a subdomain. But I still don't get how to implement single view for my sub domains. Do I need to create another pattern in hosts.py?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> A value beginning with a period can be used as a subdomain wildcard:
>   '.example.com' will match example.com, www.example.com, and any other
>   subdomain of example.com.
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts

For security purposes you must add your domains to allowed_hosts list. Just use wildcard like this:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.myproject.io']
```

2) Try HttpRequest.META["HTTP_HOST"]

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META

or request.get_host()

UPDATE:
If you want operate with multiple sites in single django application, you should use [Django Sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/sites/). You don't need django-hosts library.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. For getting subdomain I used split function: ```request.META['HTTP_HOST']..split('.', 1)[0]```

Answer (score 0):

This question seems to be vert old but I think it will be helpfull for anyone who is still searching for this.

For wildcard subdomain, adding the domain in a list does not work for me. I have to add it as a tuple.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.domain.com'] - This does not work for me

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ('.domain.com',) - This works for me.
```

I tested it on Django 2.2.5 and Django 3.6